# temper her Komsomol fervor -- what's the meaning of "temper" in this example?

Tags: meaning

Usage example with a [context:](http://observer.com/2014/12/president-of-lithuania-gets-punkd-after-declaring-russia-a-terrorist-state/)

> An angry rebuke from the Russian Ministry for Foreign Affairs immediately followed. In its statement, the representative of the Ministry made a suggestion that such hostile rhetoric by the Lithuanian president had been caused by Ms. Grybauskaitė’s “complexes about her Soviet past” and recommended that she “**temper her Komsomol fervor**.” For those too young to remember, Komsomol was a Young Communist League of the USSR — a political organization for the Soviet Communist youth.

I'm not sure how to understand that. I assume the word **temper** is used figuratively, but I can't make sense of what it means here.

Comment: It's [verb sense 2:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/temper) *Act as a neutralizing or counterbalancing force to (something)*, where the oxforddictionaries example usage is *their idealism is tempered with realism*. What's not clear about that? Credible alternatives here might be *restrain, tone down, muzzle, soften*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temper is a complex word.  Knowing the origin of temper may help you understand why it is used here.

Temper is a metalworking process. In order to work metal, several steps are needed:  The ore must be purified. The metal is softened with heat.  The hot metal is hammered into shape.  Finally, the metal is hardened so it will hold an edge and be a useful tool.

The hardening process is called tempering.  A tool that is misused and loses its hardening (or "loses its temper") becomes blunt and useless.  We often say "don't lose your temper" to people who are becoming angry because an angry person is also often blunt and useless.

In your example, the Ministry is rebuking Ms. Grybauskaitė's "hostile rhetoric" and suggesting she is being emotional. Because of her complexes and fervor, she is speaking out of anger and not being reasonable.  The Ministry suggests that until she regains control over her emotions by tempering her fervor, she should not be taken seriously.

The author also did something interesting I would like to point out.  The author says this is an "angry rebuke" from the Ministry, which implies the Ministry may have lost its temper with Ms. Grybauskaitė.  If so, all of the Ministry's arguments about why Ms. Grybauskaitė should not be taken seriously also apply to themselves!